# uwp Image Dimension can't be reset after Storyboard Animation

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp, storyboard

I am using this XAML Storyboard to implement a transition between two images named ctlIMage and altImage that are defined as follows:

```
    <Image x:Name = "ctlImage" Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment= "Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"  Stretch = "Uniform"  Opacity="0">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="image_Transform" ></CompositeTransform >
        </Image.RenderTransform >
    </Image>

        <Image x:Name = "altImage" Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment= "Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"  Stretch = "Uniform"  Opacity="0">
           <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="altImage_Transform" ></CompositeTransform >
           </Image.RenderTransform >
        </Image>

        <Storyboard x:Name="ctlImageFadeOut" Completed="SwapAltCtl">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ctlImage">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"  />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="image_Transform">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5"  />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="image_Transform">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5"  />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="altImage">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
```

When I play the animation using this code:

```
            altImage.Opacity = 0;
            altImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            altImage.Source = await MainPlayList.GetCurrentImage((int)altImage.Height, (int)altImage.Width);
            ctlImageFadeOut.Begin();
```

And use this method to swap both images at the end of the animation:

```
    private async void SwapAltCtl(object sender, object e)
    {
        ctlImage.Opacity = 0;
        image_Transform.ScaleX = 1;
        image_Transform.ScaleY = 1;
        ctlImage.Height = altImage.ActualHeight;
        ctlImage.Width = altImage.ActualWidth;
        ctlImage.Source = await MainPlayList.GetCurrentImage((int)ctlImage.Height, (int)ctlImage.Width);
        ctlImage.Opacity = 1;
        altImage.Opacity = 0;
        altImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

I end up with a half-sized ctlImage, like the ScaleX and ScaleY don't get reset after the XAML Storyboard. As you see, I've even tried to reset the Height and Width to known values (the alternate image that is already displayed).

How can we reset the image after the animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `SwapAltCtl` method, you don't need it actually. All you have to do is setting the [FillBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR210306) property of the `Storyboard` as **Stop**, the default value of this property is **HoldEnd**.

From the docs,

**FillBehavior="Stop"**

> By default, when an animation ends, the animation leaves the property value as the final To or By-modified value even after its duration is surpassed. However, if you set the value of the FillBehavior property to FillBehavior.Stop, the value of the animated value reverts to whatever the value was before the animation was applied, or more precisely to the current effective value as determined by the dependency property system (for more info on this distinction, see Dependency properties overview).

There is another line to modify. When the animation ends, you wish the `ctlImage` to be reset to initial state and become visible again, so you should set the initial value of `Opacity` for `ctlImage` as 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. However why can't I modify the ScaleX and ScaleY attribute AFTER the animation ends?

Comment: you mean, after you set FillBehavior="Stop"?

Comment: I mean: I do need the SwatAltCtl: through the rest of my code, the ctlImage is the main image that is used for other modifications. So my idea is: the ctlImage is always displayed and used for manipulations. When the user selects another image, it's loaded in atlImage which is used for the duration of the animation and then that new image then swapped back into ctlImage. Therefore, I don't want to reset the ctlImage to become visible again until it holds the new image otherwise the display flickers. This works fine with cross fades only, however I can't seem to reset the ScaleX/ScaleY

Comment: In my test, ScaleX/ScaleY are reset to 1 if  FillBehavior="Stop", and remain 0.5 if FillBehavior="HoldEnd". This is aligned with the docs.

Comment: Agreed. I get the same too. But setting image_Transform.ScaleX=1 should put them back to 1, no? In my tests, it does reset them to 1, but the image stays half-sized...??

Comment: @FrancoisGagnon this is an [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard) for this phenomenon

Comment: Thanks a lot Kennyzy. Interesting, I was just reading that very page as I received this message from you. Very useful.

Comment: Well, I thought I was done with this, but I still have the same problem. Now, with the FillBehavior="Stop", the ScaleX/ScaleY are put back to their original value. But my code cannot change them anymore afterwards. If I try to zoom in the image by changing them, nothing happens. It's like after a Storyboard has been used with a control, I can't contril it anymore. This does not affect the opacity property, only the transform controls.

Comment: I found this, not sure if/how it applies to UWP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard

Comment: this is not the case in my test. I can change image_Transform.ScaleX/Y in `SwapAltCtl`, which take effect immediately.

Comment: WTF then...... I solved the problem by adding a third <Image> to the grid and doing the animation between the second and third image... not the most efficient... I've tested my code on my laptop as well, so it's definitely not a question of VS2017 installation...